# Difference-in-differences or something else? Regrouping after intervening event

Tags: difference-in-difference

I'm working on a project for my econometrics class and I could use some help. I'm looking at the effects of a Supreme Court decision, *Tapia v. U.S*, on the length of sentences handed out for drug crimes.

Statute has long been clear that a convict's need for rehab can't be used as a reason to imprison him(as opposed to probabation), but before *Tapia*, circuits were split on whether or not the need for rehabilitation can be used to lengthen a sentence (after the prison/probation decision has been made). In *Tapia* the SC ruled that a sentence cannot be lengthened due to a convict's need for rehab. After this, the circuits split again. Some circuits allow a sentencing court to consider rehab during sentencing, as long as it isn't the dominant factor or doesn't explicitly lead to a longer sentence. Others say that any consideration of rehab during sentencing violates *Tapia.* The before-and-after split looks like this:

[image: Pre-Tapia vs Post-Tapia]
Sentencing data is readily available, so I have data from both before and after Tapia for all circuits (I'm using one from each period). Right now, I'm just doing a difference-in-differences estimations for various drug crimes between 7th/10th/11th and 2nd/3rd, as those circuits were on the same side of the split pre-Tapia. That should show me the effects of the new split, I believe. I think I could also do an estimation between 2nd/3rd and 5th/6th/8th to see the effects of *Tapia's* elimination of the original split, but I haven't done this yet.

Does this sound like the best plan to you guys? I'll obviously use as many controlling variables as I can, and I'm not worried about the law side of things. Is there a different tool I could use that could use the reshuffle to my advantage and show me the separate effects of both the end of the first split and the onset of another? I'm using Stata. Thanks.

Comment: To avoid duplicated efforts, please know that I've cross-posted with Statalist here: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1498071-difference-in-differences-or-something-else-regrouping-after-an-intervening-event

Comment: There seems to be one big issue here and that is that your groups (circuits) are all affected by the SC decision (they all take *Tapia* into account), so it may not be appropriate to treat post-*Tapia* outcomes of one group as a counterfactual of another group (i.e., to define treatment and control groups simply based on pre-decision behavior).  Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: No, that's correct. Nearly all the circuits changed their behavior after the decision. Even if they were P/P or NP/NP, SCOTUS's ruling changed the way they implemented sentences. There is no way to treat one group as the counterfactual to a Tapia ruling, since they now all operate under it.

Comment: (Continued) My goal, however, is to find the difference created by the post-decision split, or both splits (not the decision itself). That's why I'm only using circuits with the same pre-decision behavior; to isolate one split from the other. Does that make sense? And if so, is the idea flawed?

Comment: It just violates the parallel trends assumption of DiD: that in the absence of treatment, the difference between the ‘treatment’ and ‘control’ group is constant over time.  You can find a difference between two periods in one group and in another group (separately), but the DiD estimator will give you biased results.  In an extreme case, say both groups underwent the same change.  The model will give you an insignificant difference in changes between the two groups.  Or if one group did not experience a change, you won't be sure what the outcome would have been in the absence of *Tapia*.

Comment: I suppose if the question is really what the effect of permitting the use of the need for rehabilitation for lengthening a sentence is, then maybe you are okay.  But I think you'll still have to clearly show that NP/NP outcomes did not change and argue that NP/P outcomes would have followed the same trend as NP/NP in the absence of the ruling.

Comment: Thanks for your help.